# О предложных сочетаниях "в отсутствие" и "при отсутствии"

Tags: предлоги

В соответствии с ПАС сочетания "в отсутствие" и "при отсутствии" названы близкими к предлогам синонимичными сочетаниями. [Безударные гласные в падежных окончаниях | orthographia.ru](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=989)

В то же время возникает ряд вопросов:

**1) Различаются ли они по смысловым оттенкам или  стилю?** В каких случаях предпочтителен тот или другой предлог?

**2) Можно ли выделить два значения у этих предлогов?** (а. причинное /в связи с отсутствием/ и  б. временное /во время отсутствия/)

а. *В отсутствие такого закона невозможно во всех необходимых случаях привлечь к ответственности должностные лица. В отсутствие опоры плети растений укореняются и быстро расползаются по земле. То ли дело Омск, в отсутствие других сносных развлечений  живущий исключительно хоккеем.*

б. *По нормам ГПК после третьей неявки в судебное заседание без уважительной причины суд обязан рассматривать дело в отсутствие стороны.*

**3) Всегда ли они заменяют друг друга?**

*Днём, в отсутствие Ивана Григорьевича, приехала сестра Анны Сергеевны и увезла в деревню Алёшу.* [Василий Гроссман. Все течет (1955-1963) // «Октябрь», 1989]

Возможна ли здесь замена? Если нет, то почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Да, различаются. Это проявляется в ситуациях употребления. Первый вариант тяготеет к ситуациям реальным или ожидаемым  (~=ввиду отсутствия), второй - к гипотетическим (~=в случае отсутствия).

2A.Первое предложение содержит удачный пример употребления сочетания, во втором предложении по смыслу предпочтительно "**при** отсутствии", в третьем - "**за** отсутстви**ем**".

2Б. Здесь выбор сочетания тоже обоснован (*ожидаемая* ситуация).

3. Замена допустима, но нежелательна - это менее точно, поскольку при восприятии приходится отстраиваться от некоторого оттенка причинности (в варианте с "при"), который улетучивается лишь при прочтении предложения до конца.

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander, очень у Вас интересные рассуждения и классификация значений, но вот мне кажется, что вы временное (не причинно-условное) значение вообще не рассматриваете. Но вот в предложении № 3, как мне кажется, значение именно времени: "днём, когда Иван Григорьевич отсутствовал", причем предлог "при отсутствии" с этим значением не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

1. Значения этих конструкций различны: в отсутствие=в течение чьего-либо отсутствия, т.е. временное значение. Такое сочетание можно считать предлогом (как, например, "в течение"). Не понимаю, почему "при отсутсвии" считается близким к предлогу, ведь здесь предлог "при"+ обстоятельство, выраженное какой-то конструкцией (например, То ли дело Омск, при отсутствии других сносных развлечений живущий исключительно хоккеем. - (я заменил "в отсутствие" на "при отсутствии", т.к. в отсутствие - предлог, указывающий на время, в течение которого это что-то происходило) здесь "при отсутствии развлечений": при (предлог) + отсутствие развлечений (как единая конструкция, выражающая состояние). Раз "отсутствие развлечений" ведёт себя как единая конструкция при совокуплении "при", то это уже предложение. А раз оно введено в другое предложение, то вся конструкция с "при" - вводная конструкция, разъясняющая обстоятельства., а не близкая к предлогу,
2. Они не могут заменят друг друга вообще, т.к. обладают совершенно различной природой. В последнем предложении "в отсутствие" применено верно

Answer (score 0):

Sibylla:

> В соответствии с ПАС сочетания "в отсутствие" и "при отсутствии"
>   названы близкими к предлогам синонимичными сочетаниями.
>   [Безударные гласные в падежных окончаниях | orthographia.ru](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=989)

Нет, **ПАС** 'при отсутствии' не называет сочетанием, близким к предлогу.

Дословно в [**ПАС**](http://orthographia.ru/orfograf_uk.php?oid=989) сказано так:

> **§ 72…** Различаются в написании близкие к предлогам сочетания ***в отсутствие*** кого-н. ('при отсутствии') и ***в присутствии*** кого-н.

Здесь закавыченное 'при отсутствии', указанное в скобках, употреблено **для толкования** смыслового значения близкого к предлогу сочетания  ***в отсутствие*** (см. пример: ***в отсутствие** учителя дети расшалились*).

Толкование же это приведено лишь потому, что *в отсутствие* может функционировать не только как предлог с похожим на 'при отсутствии' значением, но и как и свободное сочетание предлога и существительного — напр., в таком предложении: *можно верить и **в отсутствие** веры*.

Comment: Если предложное сочетание "в отсутствие" определяется (толкуется) через предложное сочетание "в присутствии", то почему их нельзя назвать синонимами. Синонимы имеют близкое (похожее), хотя и не тождественное  значение.

Comment: _Sibylla: Если предложное сочетание "в отсутствие" определяется (толкуется) через предложное сочетание "в присутствии", то почему их нельзя назвать синонимами._ === ??? Sibylla, вчитайтесь повнимательнее в то, что Вы 10 минут назад написали.

Comment: Пожалуйста, выразите свою мысль яснее. Какое утверждение вы считает неверным, что нужно поправить? Если можно, подскажите источник (толковый словарь), где эти  сочетания считаются предложными сочетаниями или предлогами, а также где определено  их смысловое значение.

Comment: _Sibylla: Пожалуйста, выразите свою мысль яснее._ === Да уж куда ещё яснее… Повторюсь: вчитайтесь повнимательнее в свой первый комментарий!